# What does mean entitlements doesn't match provisioning profile?

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing, xcode4.5

I'm trying to submit a MacApp Store app to iTunesConnect via Xcode archiving process. But for whatever reason I can't figure out, I still get this message.

> Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. The bundle contains a key that is not included in the provisioning profile: 'com.apple.application-identifier' in 'MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp'.

I've read all issue here on stackoverflow which could be relevant, but with no success. This is driving me crazy for several hours now!

Thanks!